# Restarting And Termination a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

Below is my code in which i want to restart a thread if a condition is true .Some how i need to do it is there any way to terminate a thread and restart that thread is itpossible? for e.g

```
   private Thread demoThread = null;
         this.demoThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.StartForLoop));

          this.demoThread.Start();

    private void StartForLoop()
                        {
    if(i=0)
    {
    //restart this thread...
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to pause and resume a thread you will need to use a synchronization object, e.g. a mutex, and have the thread check at appropriate points to see if it should be taking a break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't restart a thread once it finishes executing. You can start a new thread, or use a [pool of worker threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) that are started and stay running looking for *tasks* to run and then go back to sleep.

If the tasks you want to run out of band are relatively short-lived and you need to run them frequently using the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is recommended.

If you are targeting newer version of the .Net framework it's best to consider using the new [async](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx) features in conjunction with the [Tasks API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as it provides a higher level of abstraction than simply using the ThreadPool directly to queue units of work.

However, if what you want to do is have a background thread wait as in a producer-consumer pattern then you could perhaps use a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and have your thread wait on the object to become signaled. When the event is signaled, the thread can resume and *consume* whatever it is it needs to consume and then go to sleep again until there is more to do.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread` objects can only run once.
If you want to start it again, you'll need to create a `new Thread`.